# how to give dynamic values coming from array in graph in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using EASYGRAPH for to create graph in iphone app problem is that it gets static values and shows graph i want that values should be dynamic come from view controller for this graph.

UIView For Graph

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "ECGraph.h"
 #import "ECGraphItem.h"
@class GraphsViewController;
@interface Display : UIView {

NSArray *percentages;



}

 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray*percentages;


 -(void) setPercentageArray:(NSArray*) array;

@end


  #import "Display.h"
  #import "ECGraph.h"
  @implementation Display
  @synthesize percentages;

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code.
  }
  return self;
  }


   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {


CGContextRef _context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
ECGraph *graph = [[ECGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,500,320,200) withContext:_context isPortrait:NO];



//300,500,320, 200

ECGraphItem *item1 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];

ECGraphItem *item2 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];    
item1.isPercentage = YES;
item1.yValue=80;
item1.width = 35;
item1.name = @"item1";
item2.isPercentage = YES;
item2.yValue =17;
item2.width = 35; 
item2.name = @"item2";




NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:item1,item2,nil];

[graph setXaxisTitle:@"name"];
[graph setYaxisTitle:@"Percentage"];
[graph setGraphicTitle:@"Histogram"];
[graph setDelegate:self];
[graph setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:220/255.0 green:220/255.0 blue:220/255.0 alpha:1]];



[graph drawHistogramWithItems:items lineWidth:2 color:[UIColor blackColor]];




 }
```

Comment: your question is too vague, plaese explain what do mean by dynamic and from which viewcontroller you want to get dynamic values.

Comment: I have view Controller GraphicsFrom their i want to get dynamic values I am using this view in my ViewControllers view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a class that contains two properties width and height. then add it to array using addObject. now each object has individual values of height and width.

then use this

```
for(Item* theObj in arrayItems)
{//arrayItems is the array in which you have added the objects height and width
  ECGraphItem *tempItem = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];    
  tempItem.isPercentage = YES;
  tempItem.yValue=theObj.height;
  tempItem.width = theObj.widht;
  tempItem.name = [NSString stringWithFormat@"Item: %d",/*set some number here*/];

  [items addObject:tempItem];
}
```

and then pass it to graph

```
[graph drawHistogramWithItems:items lineWidth:2 color:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: I need only height value so for one value i may create a separate class and how may i assign that values to properties can u help me

Comment: i wrote it how u assign it to proprty. and if it is only one value then us NSNumber instead of making class

Comment: lets say i have that NSNumber in GraphsViewController where i am using this View as nib then how will give value from that view controller to this item for height

Comment: write number wise steps what u want